# toLowerCase() useless parenthesis?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript and i'm taking my first few lessons. I was wondering the use of parenthesis at the end of  toLowerCase command because they do not do anything even if you put a number between them.

Can anyone explain their use?

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a *method*, the `()` invokes the method. `var x = function() {}` - even though `x` is a parameterless function, you need `()` to invoke it: `x()` - Don't confuse this with something like `Array.length` - where `length` is a *property* on the array and therefore doesn't need to be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is an interpreted language, and if you declare a function that doesn't take arguments, it's not an error to send some parameters, they will be ignored. You can access them using the predefined `arguments` variable, but it's out the question scope.

To sumarize: toLowerCase does not take any arguments, so even if you put some arguments, they will ignored. toLowerCase it's still a function, so you need the `()` at the end of the day to call it.

Answer (score 2):

`toLowerCase` is a function as opposed to a variable. Without, the `()`, `str.toLowerCase` will return the function definition.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/koralarts/jopryu8x/

`toLowerCase` usage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase